# SQL How to Delete Data from Table Using INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to delete all records form the table "oc_products" that don't have a certain category ID. I created a SELECT query that lists those products using an INNER JOIN, since the categories are in a separate table.

What I can't figure out is how to use the DELETE function to delete the shown records.

This is what my code looks like:

```
DELETE oc_product
FROM oc_product
INNER JOIN oc_product_to_category ON oc_product.product_id = oc_product_to_category.product_id
WHERE oc_product_to_category.category_id = 343
```

Its showing the error "Unexpected keyword, (near INNER JOIN)".

Comment: write a sub query to get all records and then use where clause. DELETE oc_product
FROM oc_product where oc_product in (sub query )

Comment: @sreenivas I tried it but the error **"Table 'oc_product' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data"** comes up. I understand the problem but what do I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add .* to p in your first line.

Try:

```
DELETE p.* FROM oc_product p
INNER JOIN oc_product_to_category pc ON p.product_id = 
    pc.product_id
WHERE pc.category_id = 343
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Could you perhaps explain what the " .* " does exactly, and what the "p" and "pc" stand for? Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: p and pc are aliases so that you don't have to use the full table name every time. p.* just says that delete rows from p and not from pc.